# How can I implementing own "custom component" list in angular

Tags: angular

I defined a custom element "my-button". This button has a type to setup automatically the icon and the text of this button.
E.g.

```
<my-button buttontype="add"></my-button>
<my-button buttontype="delete"></my-button>
```

...

So so far ok.

Now I want to implement the second custom element "my-menubar" which should includes a list of "my-button"

E.g.

```
<my-menubar>
<my-buttons>
<my-button buttontype="add"></my-button>
<my-button buttontype="delete"></my-button>
/my-buttons>
</my-menubar>
```

My question, how could I do this?

Comment: Inside your `my-menubar` add `my-button` component so once you add your `my-menubar` `my-button` component is also present.

Comment: sorry, I started new with angular. But how to implement my-menubar to accept a list of my-buttons by HTML code instead of adding them per code. E.g. myMenubar.buttons.push(new MyButton...)

Comment: so what are the technical term of this? Nested component? Group-Form? ...

Comment: basically you have 2 component. One is `my-member` and another one is `my-button`. you need to add the `my-button` component in to the `my-member` component. and add `my-member` when you want to show `menu` and `button`.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. I missed only the "content projection" term :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need content projection. Here is how you can achieve it

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-menubar',
  template: `
     <ng-content select="[my-buttons]"></ng-content>
  `
})
export class MyMenubarComponent {

}
```

And you can use it as follows

```html
<my-menubar>
  <div my-buttons>
    <my-button buttontype="add"></my-button>
    <my-button buttontype="delete"></my-button>
  </div>
</my-menubar>
```

I select `[my-buttons]` as attribute, otherwise you will have to create a component with selector `my-buttons`

If you want to use the component as follows

```html
<my-menubar>
  <my-buttons>
    <my-button buttontype="add"></my-button>
    <my-button buttontype="delete"></my-button>
  </my-buttons>
</my-menubar>
```

You will need to create another component as follows

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-buttons',
  template: `
     <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export class MyButtonsComponent {}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I need. Thank you so much